# Sum Of n numbers taken $k$ at a time, where numbers are of form $r\choose k$

Tags: co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series

I have an array of numbers lets call it $p$ , where $p[r]={k+r-1\choose k-1}$

I want to find the sum of all the elements of $p$ taken $n$ at a time .

$0\le r\le k$

For instance, for $k=3$ ,$n=2$ , i need

$$p[0]^2+p[1]^2+p[2]^2+p[3]^2+p[0]\cdot p[1]+p[0]\cdot p[2]+p[0]\cdot p[3]+p[1]\cdot p[2]+p[1]\cdot p[3]+\\+p[2]\cdot p[3]=\sum_{i\le j}p[i]\cdot p[j]=\sum_{i\le j}{k+i-1\choose k-1}{k+j-1\choose k-1}$$ which is $273$

Is there any way , i can solve this for any value of $k$ or $n$ without solving big equations like above

In other words , how to solve this summation?

$$\sum_{0\le x_1\le x_2...\le x_n \le n}^{}\binom{k+x_1-1}{x_1}\binom{k+x_2-1}{x_2}...\binom{k+x_n-1}{x_n}$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure why this received a downvote. You are asking for the
coefficient of $x^n$ in $F(x)=1/\prod_{r=0}^k (1-{k+r-1\choose
k-1}x)$. Since the denominator of $F(x)$ has distinct explicit zeros,
one can explicitly find the partial fraction expansion of $F(x)$ and
then expand each term. For instance, when $k=3$ we get
  $$ F(x) = \frac{1}{(1-x)(1-3x)(1-6x)(1-10x)} $$
  $$ \ =
     \frac{250}{63(1-10x)}-\frac{18}{5(1-6x)}+\frac{19}{14(1-3x)}
     -\frac{1}{90(1-x)}. $$
The coefficient of $x^n$ is therefore
$\frac{250}{63}10^n-\frac{18}{5}6^n +\frac{19}{14}3^n-\frac{1}{90}$.